# Yellow Pages Scraper in Python Not working

Tags: python, web-scraping, yellow-pages

I am trying to scrape data from Yellow Pages. I  used this scraper many times, but it has recently stopped.

Got this error

> `'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group' 0 results found`

can anyone please help me to fix this problem

Where am I going wrong on this?

```
import requests
import requests_random_user_agent
import urllib.parse
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re
from math import ceil
import csv
import os
import sys
import subprocess
from os import system, name
import time
from tqdm import tqdm



class Scraper:
    def __init__(self,keyword,location):
        self.keyword=keyword
        self.location=location
        self.params = urllib.parse.urlencode({"search_terms": self.keyword, "geo_location_terms": self.location})

    def get_info(self, link):

        try:
            r = requests.get(link)
            html = BeautifulSoup(r.content, "html.parser")
        except:
            return False
        
        try:
            name = html.find('h1').text
        except:
            name = None
            
        try:
            phone = html.find(class_='phone').text
        except:
            phone = None
            
        
        try:

            website = html.find('a',class_='primary-btn website-link')["href"]

            if len(website.split("?")) > 1:
                website = website.split("?")[0]

        except:
            website = None
            

        try:
            email = html.find('a', class_='email-business')["href"].split(":")[1]
        except:
            email=None
        
        try:
            address = html.find('h2',class_='address').text
        except:
            address=None

        return {"name": name, "email": email, "phone": phone, "address": address, "website":website}
    
    def get_num_pages(self):

        try:
            url = f"https://www.yellowpages.com/search?{self.params}"

            response = requests.get(url)

            html = BeautifulSoup(response.content, "html.parser")
            pagination = html.find(class_="pagination")
            
            if not pagination:
                pagination = 1
                links = html.select("a[class='business-name']")

                num_results = 0
            
                for l in links:
                    try:
                        l["data-analytics"]
                        num_results += 1
                    except:
                        continue

                return num_results, pagination
            
            
            num_results = int(re.search('We found(.*?)results',pagination.text).group(1))


            return num_results, int(ceil(int(num_results) / 30))
            
        except Exception as e:
            print(e)
            return False, False

    def get_links(self, page):
        
        try:
            url = f"https://www.yellowpages.com/search?{self.params}&page={page}"

            response = requests.request("GET", url, timeout=10)
            html = BeautifulSoup(response.content, "html.parser")
            links = html.select("a[class='business-name']")

            links_filtered=[]
            
            for l in links:
                try:
                    l["data-analytics"]
                    links_filtered.append(l)
                except:
                    continue

            links_list = []

            for link in links_filtered:
                links_list.append(f"https://www.yellowpages.com{link['href']}")
            

            return links_list
        except Exception as e:
            print(e)
            return []

def open_file(filename):

    try:
        if sys.platform == "win32":
            os.startfile(filename)
        else:
            opener = "open" if sys.platform == "darwin" else "xdg-open"
            subprocess.call([opener, filename])
    except:
        return False

def create_csv(elements):


    row_list = [["Name", "Address", "Phone", "Email", "Website"]]

    for e in elements:
        
        name = e["name"]
        address = e["address"]
        phone = e["phone"]
        email = e["email"]
        website = e["website"]

        row_list.append([name, address, phone, email, website])

    with open('output.csv', 'w', newline='', encoding='utf8') as file:
        writer = csv.writer(file)
        writer.writerows(row_list)

    


def clear():

    # for windows
    if name == 'nt':
        _ = system('cls')

    # for mac and linux(here, os.name is 'posix')
    else:
        _ = system('clear')


def main():

    clear()

    try:

        while True:
            keyword = input("Keyword: ")
            
            if keyword != "":
                break


        while True:
            city = input("City: ")
            if city != "":
                break

        clear()


        scraper = Scraper(keyword, city)

        results, num_pages = scraper.get_num_pages()

        if not results:
            print("0 results found")
            return False

        print(f"{results} results found {keyword} - {city}")

        data = []

        pages = tqdm(range(1, num_pages + 1))

        for page in pages:
            clear()
            try:
                pages.set_description(f"Scraping page {page}/{num_pages}...")


                links = scraper.get_links(page)

                if not (len(links) > 0):
                    continue

                links = tqdm(links)

                for link in links:
                    try:
                        links.set_description(f"Scraping {link}")

                        info = scraper.get_info(link)
                        # print(info)
                        data.append(info)

                        create_csv(data)

                    except:
                        continue

            except:
                continue
        
        

        print("Opening file...")

        open_file("output.csv")

        print("Task finished")

    except:
        return False

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Answer (score 1):

It fails on the line

```
num_results = int(re.search('We found(.*?)results',pagination.text).group(1))
```

A very *simple* check of the search results page, by opening the browser, would have shown you that the text "We found x results" is not present on the page. So `re.search` returns `None`, even if there are many results.

Adjust your script to work without `num_pages` and only paginate via the page links at the bottom or by incrementing the `page=` parameter in the URL until no more results/pages are listed.

FYI, next time, put in some minimal debugging effort and not post your entire script.